# angular js - Return promise instead data object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, spring-data-rest

im working with angular.

In my `service.js` I'm trying to return some values but instead data I get the `promise` item with some **$$variables** & the data Im looking for.

Problem is I can't work with data since it's a promise. How can I get **only** the **data object**?

```
function loadLinks(respuesta,link) {
  return SpringDataRestAdapter.process(respuesta, link)
    .then(function (results) {
      return results;
    });
}
```

Im using [Spring Data Rest](http://guylabs.ch/project/angular-spring-data-rest/). I copied this from another service which was working, but this one is not working well.

Any help?

Thanks you!

Comment: How about returning `results.data` or whatever the property may be called?

Comment: I dont know, thats what Im looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't do any additional logic, you can just return the function which already is a promise:

```
function loadLinks(respuesta,link) {
    return SpringDataRestAdapter.process(respuesta, link);
}
```

And where you use it:

```
myService.loadLinks(respuesta, link).then(function(result) {
    $scope.results = result;
}, function() {
    // fail
});;
```

---

If you do want to have additional logic, you can use the $q service:

```
function loadLinks(respuesta,link) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    SpringDataRestAdapter.process(respuesta, link)
        .then(function (results) {
            // do something more
            console.log(results);
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject();
        });;

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: I think I used it without success. Let me check it!

Comment: `SpringDataRestAdapter.process()` already returns a promise, why creating another one? **Edit**: @devqon edited his answer to return the function.

Comment: Seems like yes, @iWörk , because im using `.then()`. Anyway, not getting the correct answer. Do you know how to "process" it to get only data instead a promise item?

Comment: @JorgeBaumann you do have to use promises, because it is an async call

Comment: You can't, since it's an asynchronous operation.

Comment: Yaaay! It works, with the 1st solution @devqon . Now im getting only data instead promise item. Thanks you very much!

Comment: Please avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) (in the second part of your answer)!